# G++ Compiler for Arm doesn't find freetype.h

Tags: c++, linux, arm, freetype

I tryp to compile a native Linux-Project with Code:Blocks for an arm platform. The code is compiling well, if I use the standard g++ and gcc compilers. But when I set the toolchain like in this [tutorial](http://www.valvers.com/embedded-linux/beaglebone/step06-cross-compiling/), it seem to doesn't find ftheader.h from the freetype library. I've set the search path to "/usr/include/freetype2/config/". But mow he searches in "arm-linux-gnueabi/freetype2/config/" (where is nothing).

Comment: how does the actual invokation of the compiler look like?

Comment: How do I see that in Codeblocks?